# Chart.js line chart: gap between December and January

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js

I have a line chart, which shows monthly dynamics of `cumulative data` over the years, which starts from 0 each year.

How to make a gap between December and January for each year? In other words, how to connect dots only if the value increases?

There is an option to add null data and use `spangaps`, but that's the last option.

[image]

Comment: I was looking for another solution but only with `null` you can implement this

Comment: can you show an example of data?

Comment: do you have variables with start and end data?

Comment: Doesn't your data have to be an array?

Comment: Yes, it is an array. Well, if the solution is to add null data, I'll find a workaround. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for minimum and maximum date and create a dictionary with all available date and for non-available data you can set it to null

```js
const data = [
  {
    date: "2019-12-01T00:00:00",
    value: "50",
  },
  {
    date: "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    value: "10",
  },
];

const dataDates = data.map(({ date, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, date: new Date(date) }));

const minDate = Math.min(...dataDates.map(({ date }) => date.getTime()));
const maxDate = Math.max(...dataDates.map(({ date }) => date.getTime()));

const dataDictionary = dataDates.reduce((acc, { date, ...rest }) => {
  const dateKey = date.getTime();
  acc[dateKey] = { date, ...rest };

  return acc;
}, {});

const chartJsData = [];

let currentDate = minDate;

while (currentDate <= maxDate) {
  if (dataDictionary[currentDate])
    chartJsData.push(dataDictionary[currentDate]);
  else
    chartJsData.push({ date: new Date(currentDate), value: null });

  // Increment date with 1 month
  currentDate = currentDate + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
}

console.log(chartJsData)
```